# Invalid argument error thrown for selenium script

Tags: python, file, selenium

I have a file full of Urls (about some 3000 urls) and the requirement is to get each url invoked in a browser tab and click on each page (just the click is enough on the loaded page), which redirects to a different page. This is all I need to do.

I have written a code for the urls to retrieve one by one and clink on the page (page is designed to click anywhere to land or redirect to a different page). However, while running the code an error is being thrown with "invalid argument". Any thoughts, how can I correct the error ?

Appreciate your support.

```
    with open(dataFile, 'r') as urlFile:
        urlFile.readline()
        for url in urlFile:
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
            driver.get(url)
            link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body")
            link.click()
        urlFile.close()
```

The above code should pull each url from the file on a new browser tab and click. Repeat the same until all the urls in the file are done.

Comment: which line you are getting the error? and is there any blank lines in the text file. also, check the URL format and it should be starting link http:// or https://

Comment: @Murthi, you are correct. I have the /r (carriage return) in my code and I have it removed and it is working good. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @Murthi, I have another problem with this code. Let's say, I have n lines of Urls in the file - however, the code executes n-1 and leaves the last Urls from the file. Any suggestions, please ?

Comment: remove the code urlFile.readline() in the loop(second line in your code). then it will execute all the lines.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works brilliantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something like this
**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('driver_location')

f = open("dataFile.txt", 'r')
for line in f:
    driver.get(line)
    link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#header > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > a")
    link.click()
    print(driver.current_url)

f.close()
```

**url in dataFile.txt file**

```
http://automationpractice.com/index.php
http://automationpractice.com/index.php
http://automationpractice.com/index.php
```

**output**

```
http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=order
http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=order
http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=order
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked well too. So, I have removed the /r from my code to output the urls to the file. It is working good. However, I have n lines of Urls in the file - however, the code executes n-1 and leaves the last Urls from the file.  Any good suggestions, please ?

Comment: With example above it is executing all URLs. I tried with three as shown above.